# Obtener valores con scraping

Tags: php, scraping

Holis, les comento que tengo que traer los datos de pizarra de la bolsa y no puedo obtener los valores de la pizarra y me da este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: curl_getinfo(): Argument #2 ($option) must be of type ?int, string given in

Y solo tengo que mostrar los precios y los estimados. Gracias.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.cac.bcr.com.ar/es');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

//echo 'HTTP Status Code: ' . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) . PHP_EOL;
//echo 'Response Body: ' . $response . PHP_EOL;

echo curl_getinfo($ch, '//*[@id="main-container"]/div/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]').PHP_EOL;

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Según [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-getinfo.php), no estás usando bien curl_getinfo: `curl_getinfo($handle, (int)$option=null)`. De hecho lo tienes en una de las líneas comentadas, el segundo argumento debe ser un entero y le estás pasando una cadena.

Comment: Gracias, perdón, soy muy novata todavía, no logre entenderte. Mil disculpas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu objetico es tomas los precios de la web `https://www.cac.bcr.com.ar/es`, hay muchas formas de hacerlo... dejo un ejemplo de varios...

```
$url = 'https://www.cac.bcr.com.ar/es';
$cont = file_get_contents($url);

$price = preg_match_all('/<div class="price">(.*?)<\/div>/s', $cont, $matches);

print_r($matches); // devuelve un array de todos los valores que necesitas

echo $matches[0][0]; // elijo que valor quiero ver a través de los índices
```